# Should I use Zend_Auth?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

My authentication system is very customized, I do certain things that are not normally done, right now I can register, and authenticate, and get the user identity from a session that I store.

My question is if I can do all of these with what I have build so far, is there a reason to use Zend_Auth? What I'm interested to know is if Zend_Auth really ads anything that I currently don't have.

So does Zend_Auth do anything other than Authenticating the user against a table, and remembering the identity of the user?

Comment: nope, thats pretty much what authentication is. Tha advantage of Zend Auth is with the ability to not only authenticate against a DB but also against LDAP and other custom authentication services without changing your code at all :) You just need to add a different adapter and viola, works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Auth won't build again a brand new concept of what Auth is. You can customize all the authentification process around a user by extending or reusing a Zend_Auth_Adapter.

The main "+" that it might add is the [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html)  integration that might help you to restrict the usage of some modules of your webapp to some users according to their role.

Comment: You can use Zend_Acl regardless of whether you're using Zend_Auth

Comment: Indeed but they are usually used together